# How to debug apis in PHP (without using var_dump();die();)

Tags: php, api, breakpoints, xdebug

So I'm writing an api in php, and I'd like to use a full-service debugging tool. i.e., set breakpoints, view stack traces, inspect variables, etc. This kind of thing is very common in compiled languages.

I've checked out xdebug, and after configuring it to work with phpstorm (my IDE), I was disappointed to find that it only works when I `run` from within phpstorm, not when I actually service real api requests.

To add additional complexity to this, the api dbs are actually hosted on a vagrant instance, so although I write and edit code on my local machine, the code being run is in a virtual machine vagrant environment.

Any other way of doing this? Or should I just get used to something along the lines of `print_r();exit;` and rerun the request?

Answer (score 2):

Use XDebug, and configure it properly. You can configure it to work without running the code from PhpStorm quite easily.

```
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.remote_connect_back = on
xdebug.idekey = "vagrant"
```

Make sure those are set. Then, in PhpStorm, there is something that looks like a phone icon in the top right (along with the rest of the debugging and running stuff in the toolbar). Make sure that is all green (i.e. listening for connections).

You can use Xdebug to set breakpoints. It'll even work with CLI apps if you've set it up properly. You can even debug code from inside Vagrant VMs, or on remote servers.

You just need to do some research into how to set up your IDE. ;)

More details: http://www.sitepoint.com/install-xdebug-phpstorm-vagrant/

This may come in handy for you: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/marklets/

And this: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/configuring-xdebug.html

And this: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm

Answer (score 0):

Php xdebug

Take a look this example: http://www.sitepoint.com/install-xdebug-phpstorm-vagrant/

Comment: The same here....Did you read the question properly? the Op already tried xdebug and was disappointed.

Comment: You can set phpstorm to connect to xdebug on vagrant, and xddebug will listen for your breackpoints.

Comment: You can also use tools like php debug bar (used for example in Yii framework)

Answer (score -1):

best tool available for php debugging is Xdebug. http://xdebug.org/ here is homepage.

Comment: Did you read the question? "I've checked out xdebug, and after configuring it to work with phpstorm (my IDE), I was disappointed"

Comment: Yes I had. But still Xdebug is best solution for this even you don't like it.

Comment: I think you problem is English... Who said I didn't like xdebug ?